# combining inequalities

Tags: calculus, inequality

Consider the inequality:
$$
x < \min(1/a,1/b) $$
and the inequality:
$$
x<\frac{1}{(a+b)/2}
$$
Is there a way to combine these two inequality? Is subtracting the two inequalities and getting a relation between $a$ and $b$ enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first inequality implies the second assuming $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, thanks to $\min (a,b) \leq \frac{a+b}{2} \leq \max(a,b)$ and the monotonicity of $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ on $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ or $\mathbb{R}^*_-$, so that's one way of combining them I guess.
If $a$ and $b$ are allowed to have different signs however, then all you can do is say that $x < \min(1/a,1/b,2/(a+b))$.